# Sharepoint Custom Filter Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, filter, web-parts

I want to create a custom web part that has more than 1 filter web part and that can be connected to Report Viewer Web Part (Integrated Mode) at runtime/design time.

I searched a lot for this, but could not find a way to have single web part that is a provider to more than 1 filters.

Say for example -

1. My `Report` accepts 2 parameter `Department` and `Region`.
2. I want to connect both parameters with single web part having two drop down (one for `Department` and one for `Region`)
3. Values from both the drop down should be passed to `Department` and `Region`
4. `Report` should be rendered in Report Viewer Web Part

**Solution Tried so far**

1. Create a web part that adds two custom drop down
2. Custom drop down class that implements from `ITransformableFilterValues`
3. Have 2 methods on the web pat each having `ConnectionProvider` attribute and return instance of drop down control

**Problem:**

Even though 2 connection option is shown on my custom filter web part only one can be added.
 For example if I connect `Filter1`(custom web part) to `Department` then I am unable to connect it to `Report Viewer` web part again.

My web part have methods like this:

```
[ConnectionProvider("Departmet", "UniqueIDForDept", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)] 
public ITransformableFilterValues ReturnCity() 
{ 
    return dropDownDepartment; // It implemets ITransformableFilterValues 
} 

[ConnectionProvider("Region", "UniqueIDForRegion", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)] 
public ITransformableFilterValues ReturnMyRegionB() 
{ 
    return dropDownRegion; //It implemets ITransformableFilterValues 
}
```

Comment: This is actually an inherit problem in ASP. [http://forums.asp.net/p/1118366/2646773.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/p/1118366/2646773.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. This might help point you in the right direction.  I used data in a form library to create a detailed report. I used reporting services and connected to sharepoint using web services. http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx. The report parameter I used was the item ID or GUID. Then I configured my report viewer. On the form library I used JavaScript to override the context menu to add "View Report". On the report page I used a Query String filter to grab the item ID out of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to fix your problem..

Actually I tried with `AllowsMultipleConnections = true` and it worked fine:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;


using aspnetwebparts = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities;
using wsswebparts = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

namespace FromMultiSource
{
    [Guid("a0d068dd-9475-4055-a219-88513e173502")]
    public class MultiSource : aspnetwebparts.WebPart
    {
        List<wsswebparts.IFilterValues> providers = new List<wsswebparts.IFilterValues>();
        public MultiSource()
        {
        }

        [aspnetwebparts.ConnectionConsumer("Multiple Source Consumer", "IFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
        public void SetConnectionInterface(wsswebparts.IFilterValues provider)
        {
            this.providers.Add(provider);
            if (provider != null)
            {
                List<wsswebparts.ConsumerParameter> l = new List<wsswebparts.ConsumerParameter>();
                l.Add (new wsswebparts.ConsumerParameter ("Value", wsswebparts.ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsMultipleValues | Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsAllValue));
                provider.SetConsumerParameters(new ReadOnlyCollection<wsswebparts.ConsumerParameter>(l));
            }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            // TODO: add custom rendering code here.
            // Label label = new Label();
            // label.Text = "Hello World";
            // this.Controls.Add(label);
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.RenderContents(writer);
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            foreach (wsswebparts.IFilterValues provider in this.providers)
            {
                if (provider != null)
                {
                    string prop = provider.ParameterName;
                    ReadOnlyCollection<string> values = provider.ParameterValues;
                    if (prop != null && values != null)
                    {
                        writer.Write("<div>" + SPEncode.HtmlEncode(prop) + ":</div>");
                        foreach (string v in values)
                        {
                            if (v == null)
                            {
                                writer.Write("<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>&quot;(empty)&quot;/null</i></div>");
                            }
                            else if (v.Length == 0)
                            {
                                writer.Write("<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>empty string</i></div>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                writer.Write("<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + v + "</div>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.Write("<div>No filter specified (all).</div>");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write("<div>Not connected.</div>");
                }

                writer.Write("<hr>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```